# Lifting a table using linear rails and linear actuators

Tags: structural-engineering, design, finite-element-method, linear-motion, linear-motors

I'm trying to design a coffee table for a tightly constrained space that can lift up to become a dining table. I've drawn the CAD for this design, but I'm concerned that the moment arm on the linear-rail-to-extending-arm might be too large. Here are some photos showing the design:

Legend:

- black = steel square tubing, mostly around 2x2x1/16"
- purple/pink = linear rail
- white = linear actuator
- clear/glass = steel channel

Figure 1: table in down position
[image]

Figure 2: table in up position
[image]

Figure 3: Table base (black), linear rail base (purple), linear actuator base (white) -- all of these are affixed to each other and static. The base will be bolted to the floor.

This is essentially a steel frame constructed from steel square tubing, with linear actuators and linear rail fastened to it. The frame serves two purposes: supporting the overall structure, and ensuring parallelness between the linear actuator/rail bases.

[image]

Figure 4: All the moving pieces (the table itself, the linear actuator extension arm, the linear rail sliding blocks, and the steel channels. Again, the steel channels ensure that the linear actuator/rail components stay parallel.

[image]

Figure 5: one more "dissected" view of the system, if the base and the top were "pulled apart": [image]

I have several concerns with this design:

- the table is 18", and extends to 30". Hence, it rises 12". This means the maximum I could get the linear rail slide blocks to "overlap" was ~5.8" (See Figure 6). I'm guessing this means that whatever sideways forces the table encounters when it is raised to its maximum height, will be multiplied by 3x due to the 18/5.8 arm.

I'm relatively confident that my system can handle well over 8-10x of the supposed load (~100-150 lbs), but I'm not sure if the extra leverage will make it difficult to slide the blocks up and down, or even damage the linear rails over time.

Figure 6:

[image]

To complete the context with some details:

- Weight of the lifted components is ~100 lbs
- Table is 18" at lowest, 30" at highest.
- Linear motion (stroke) of 12"
- Linear rail slide blocks are 5.8" from end to end (total length covered by opposite ends of the blocks).
- The system is mounted in a mobile home vehicle, so dynamic forces are present -- hence, I'm hoping to make the system 3-5x stronger (or even more?) than it theoretically needs to be.

Comment: do not expect the two linear actuators to move in unison, unless the two are synchronized in some way